# Handling double results in PHP/MMSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I need the name of the employee  to be displayed once and next to each name their phone number,if the employee has additional phone number it needs to be displayed next to the first one, so far what I getting is every time the employee has additional phone number php writing his name again .

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=eshop;charset=utf8', 'root', '');
$sql = "SELECT e.firstName,e.lastName,p.phone FROM employees AS e";
$sql .= " LEFT JOIN phones AS p ON p.employeeID = e.employeeID";
$sql .= " ORDER BY e.firstName ASC";
$query = $db->prepare($sql);
$query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$query->execute();
$result = $query->fetchAll();
$table = "<table>";
$table .= "<td>Employee</td>";
$table .= "<td>Phones</td>";
foreach($result as $row){ 
    $table .= "<tr>";
    $table .= "<td> {$row->firstName} {$row->lastName} </td>";
    $table .= "<td> {$row->phone}</td>";
 }
$table .= "</table>";
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div><?= $table ; ?> </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can use `GROUP BY` along with `GROUP_CONCAT` to resolve this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Answer (score 2):

```
$sql = "SELECT e.firstName,e.lastName, GROUP_CONCAT(p.phone) as phone FROM employees AS e";
$sql .= " LEFT JOIN phones AS p ON p.employeeID = e.employeeID";
$sql .= " GROUP BY p.employeeID ORDER BY e.firstName ASC";
```

Use this query hope this will help you

**EDIT:**

Explanation to group by and group_concat of mysql

you can use GROUP BY to group values from a column and GROUP_CONCAT function to show those group value in single row.

But also note that GROUP_CONCAT has limit in mysql you can increase this limit by updating value of group_concat_max_len  variable.

```
SET group_concat_max_len = 2048;
```

Comment: Thank you,it works perfectly!However I don't quite understand the GROUP_CONCAT and GROUP BY  in this case ...can you please explain more?

Comment: You can use GROUP BY to group values from a column and GROUP_CONCAT function to show those group value in single row

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Thanks Sir

Answer (score 0):

There is more than 1 possiblities to achieve,

1: use group contact for phone number on phone table
Ex: select group_concat(phoneno), employeename from employee left join phone on phone.Employeeid = employee. Employeeid.
2: multiple query
First fetch employee then with employee ref fetch phone and change the code of loop